# How to fix implementation jwt with dingo in lumen 5.8.*? Target [Dingo\Api\Contract\Routing\Adapter] is not instantiable

Tags: php, lumen, dingo-api, jwt

I have implemented tymon/jwt-auth version 1.0.0-rc4.1 as third-party in my Lumen(5.8.4) application and now when I continue with implementing Authetication with Dingo following https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Authentication at step where I need to add this (or any other way registering jwt with dingo)

```
app('Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth')->extend('jwt', function ($app) {
   return new Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT($app['Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth']);
});
```

to app.php I get this error

Error: Target [Dingo\Api\Contract\Routing\Adapter] is not instantiable while building [Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth, Dingo\Api\Routing\Router].

I think I've searched and tried all the things that exists on internet on this theme because I'm working on it for 2 days, and most of them are using old version of dingo and/or Lumen.  I've also tried different adapters I've found on git but non of them works.

This is my setup:
composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "dingo/api": "^2",
        "flipbox/lumen-generator": "^5.6",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.8.*",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.17",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc4.1",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^3.3"
    }
```

app.php

```
app('Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth')->extend('jwt', function ($app) {
    return new Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT($app['Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth']);
}); <- this makes problem, without this everything works, I even get jwt in postman

$app->register(Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Dingo\Api\Provider\LumenServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
```

Anyone worked with implementation on newer versions, or have some better way of doing this? 
I've tried one working example
https://github.com/krisanalfa/lumen-jwt but as I saw last update was 2 years ago and Lumen version is 5.4. 
Should I maybe use it or it is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've finally get it to work. If someone run into the same problem, I've done next, in AppServiceProvider I've registered

```
use Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT;
```

and in boot method in the same file:

```
public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

        app('Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth')->extend('jwt', function ($app) {
   return new JWT($app['Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth']);
});
    }
```

in auth.php

```
  'defaults' => [
        'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'api'),
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users'
        ],
    ],
```

in jwt.php

```
 'providers' => [

        'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Lcobucci::class,

        'auth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\Illuminate::class,

        'storage' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\Illuminate::class,
    ],
```

and then protect route, for example:

```
 $api->group(['middleware' => 'api.auth'], function ($api) {
        $api->get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
    });
```

Also, quick note, if you are having an Exception "Token Signature Could not be verified", remove quotes when sending jwt through POSTMAN :)

Best regards.